# SmoothDivScroll plugin - IE locks up completely when dragging scroller to the left

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, smooth-scrolling

I've set up the [SmoothDivScroll plugin 1.3](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) on a page, within a popup window.

Simplified init function, fires plugin and sets width of scrollable area based on length of content:

```
$('.slider').smoothDivScroll({
  hotSpotScrolling: false,
  touchScrolling: true,
  manualContinuousScrolling: true
}).find('.scrollableArea').css('width', count * 140 );
```

Simplified markup:

```
<div class='slider'>
  <div class="portrait" style="background-image: url(img/bios/testing-thumb1.jpg);"></div>
  <div class="portrait" style="background-image: url(img/bios/testing-thumb2.jpg);"></div>
  <div class="portrait" style="background-image: url(img/bios/testing-thumb3.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

CSS, 'scrollWrapper' and 'scrollableArea' are both created by the plugin when initialized:

```
.slider { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border-top: 2px solid #000; border-bottom: 2px solid #000; height: 168px; width: 880px; }

.slider .scrollWrapper { position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.slider .scrollableArea { position: relative; width: auto; height: 100%; }

.slider .portrait { display: block; float: left; padding: 0 5px; width: 130px; height: 168px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px; background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.slider .portrait:hover, .slider .portrait.active { background-position: center bottom; }
.slider .portrait:after { display: none; content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 5px; height: inherit; width: inherit; pointer-events: none; }
.slider .portrait:hover:after { display: block; background-image: url(../img/popup-about-team-hover.png); }
```

[Click here to see development build](http://www.crackin.com/dev/matrix/support.php)
(scroll down and click the green 'check directory' button)

Works fine in Chrome and Firefox... however in IE (of course) you are able to scroll to the right (click and drag to the left) fine, but if you try and scroll to the left (click and drag right) then the browser quickly locks up, is totally frozen and must be killed via taskmanager.

I don't understand exactly what the plugin is doing to the DOM well enough to know where to look for problems at this point.

---

I did have one other questions about the plugin, not related to this IE issue. I can remove this and post as a separate question if needed though:

Q) How could I go about implementing a left/right slide for this slider, using the arrow keys on the keyboard? I know how to bind something to the keys, but I can't seem to figure out how to translate the handler into an action for the plugin.

Comment: The 'count' variable in the init function is just the total number of portrait objects in the slider. It's populated dynamically, there' aren't just 3 (I just put three to show the markup).

Comment: Can anybody confirm that they are actually able to see/recreate the issue from the build link provided above?

Comment: Yes, i am able to recreate the issue from above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this issue and found that your version of `jquery.kinetic` present within `plugin.js` is causing the problem. I am not sure why this is happening as I haven't compared the version of kinetic.js of yours with the version used on smoothdivscroll.com. But if you simply update your `plugin.js` to replace the code for `jquery.kinetic` with the compressed/minified version of `http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/js/jquery.kinetic.js` then I believe everything will work without an issue.

Please follow below steps:

  1) open URL http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/js/jquery.kinetic.js and copy JS code from there.

  2) with the help of online JS compressor like http://javascriptcompressor.com/; minify the above copied code and save it in temporary file.

  3) open your /js/plugin.js and comment out the existing code for jquery.kinetic and add above compressed code there.

  4) run the demo page and it will work on IE too.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down for me. I'll update the code when I get back to work next week and send the bounty your way if this works. I'm not sure why my version ended up being different than what's on the smoothdivscroll site, since I'm not using kinetic for anything other than that plugin...